# Irritating warning in Notification handler

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

I have used this bit of code for ages - it is based on the Microsoft example, and it works fine:

```
public class NotificationBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = null!;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I recently went through my code doing a warnings purge, and the only one I have left is the one relating to this. The initial setting of PropertyChangedEventHandler to null gives me a CS8612 (Nullability of reference types in type of 'event PropertyChangedEventHandler NotificationBase.PropertyChanged' doesn't match implicitly implemented member 'event PropertyChangedEventHandler? INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged').

I know in the grand scheme of things it is not important, but does anyone know how to get rid of this without suppressing the message itself?

Comment: `event PropertyChangedEventHandler?`?

Comment: `= null!;` wasn't aware that was legal.

Comment: @Fildor the exclamation mark only exists so that developer can tell the compiler "look, I know this can't be checked on compile time, but I guarantee it will not generate a null reference exception on runtime, so I don't need the possible null warning, thanks". see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, I know. Still looks peculiar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example predates nullable reference types. If you look at the documentation for the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event for a version older than .NET 5, you'll see this:

```cs
event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

That same documentation for .NET 5 and later shows this:

```cs
event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
```

Logic dictates that, if you're going to set something to `null`, it needs to be nullable. Your event signature does not match that of the interface you're implementing from .NET 5 onwards, which is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: Thanks for that - I knew it would be something simple!

Comment: Anyone able to get Microsoft to add "We changed PropertyChangedEventHandler to be nullable" to that error message?

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy, firstly, they didn't do that. They changed the `PropertyChanged` event to be nullable. The type of that event is `PropertyChangedEventHandler` and the `?` indicates that the value can be null. If you declared a variable `string? name;` it would not be `string` that is nullable but `name`, i.e. `name`1 can refer to a `string` object or no object. Secondly, there's no need to for them to tell you because every event is nullable. A non-nullable event would be one that could never not have at least one handler, which wouldn't make sense.

Comment: So why are they telling me "Nullability of reference types in type of 'event PropertyChangedEventHandler NotificationBase.PropertyChanged' doesn't match implicitly implemented member 'event PropertyChangedEventHandler? INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged'" if there's no need.

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy, firstly, there's no need for them to tell you about this event specifically because EVERY event has been changed the same way, simply by virtue of how events work and nullable reference types work. For them to change every error message to tell you the same thing that you ought to already know would be rather silly. Secondly, telling you that they changed something would also be rather silly, as it would only be valid for the first version containing that change. Telling you in .NET 20 that something has changed when it changed in .NET 6 is actually misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a hundert per cent sure, but you might get rid of the warning if you declared *PropertyChangedEventHandler* as nullable.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged = null!;
```